# Does a concentration spell still require concentration when triggered by Contingency?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

Does a spell that normally requires concentration, but which is cast with and triggered by Contingency, still require concentration once it begins?

Part of the reason I ask is in comparison with a similar situation, in which a concentration spell cast into, and then triggered by, a Glyph of Warding lasts for full duration without concentration being required of anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, the contingent spell will still require concentration.

In 5e spells do only what they say they do. *Contingency* says nothing about modifying the effects of the contingent spell.

> You cast that spell--called the contingent spell--as part of casting contingency, expending spell slots for both, but the contingent spell doesn't come into effect. Instead, it takes effect when a certain circumstance occurs. [...]
>
> The contingent spell takes effect immediately after the circumstance
> is met for the first time, whether or not you want it to, and then
> contingency ends.

The only things *contingency* changes about the spell are that the effect is delayed until the condition is met and the target is changed to only target the person who cast *contingency*. Nothing about changing concentration or duration.

Compare this to *Glyph of Warding* (a spell that is similar in some ways to *contingency*) which specifically says:

> If the spell requires concentration, it lasts until the end of its
> full duration.

Since there is no such wording in *contingency*, there is no reason to think that it does change anything to the contingent spell except what it is written in the spell effect already. **Thus, the contingent spell will require concentration once it is triggered.**

#### Official ruling - concentration is required

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/943240349379522560) agrees with the above in this clarification:

> Q: Contingency: if the spell stored requires Concentration, do you
> need to maintain concentration on it when Contingency is triggered?
>
> A: The contingent spell stored by contingency doesn't come into effect
> until its condition is met. When that happens, the contingent spell
> functions as normal, including its duration.

Answer (score 10):

The wording of *contingency* is a bit vague when it talks about the "effect" of the spell. Discusson about what similar wording exactly means is common (for example about *rings of spell storing*). The book does not clarify this, but we can fall back on a bit of logic here:

1. The spell should have its original duration. Nothing says it changes, and if it did what would it be?
2. Concentration is an attribute of a spell's duration. It is listed there on p.203 of the PHB and in that row in every spell description.

So yes, concentration spells cast as part of *contingency* will require your concentration when activated.