# Would a Contingencied Banishment protect against a triggering spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

Let's say Bob the Wizard is afraid of [*meteor swarm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meteor-swarm)s, and uses [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) to set up a [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) spell with the following trigger: "If someone casts a *meteor swarm* in an area that includes me, cast *banishment* on myself."

I know that *contingencied* Concentration spells do still require your concentration. So, he would shortly lose his concentration on *banishment*, as that spell makes you incapacitated when you’re banished.

**But would Bob still avoid the *meteor swarm* damage by that strategy (or in other words, lose his concentration and reappear AFTER the *meteor swarm* is finished)?**

Comment: Related: [Does a concentration spell still require concentration when triggered by Contingency?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/does-a-concentration-spell-still-require-concentration-when-triggered-by-conting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a concentration spell still require concentration when triggered by Contingency?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/does-a-concentration-spell-still-require-concentration-when-triggered-by-conting)

Comment: So basically how long does blinking in and out from banishing myself take?

Comment: @christian yes. And no this is not a dupplicate

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131049/what-is-the-order-of-events-when-a-contingency-spell-is-triggered-by-a-reaction.

Answer (score 11):

## *Contingency* takes place after its trigger, so the trigger you suggested wouldn't prevent damage from *meteor swarm*

From the description of the [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) spell:

> The contingent spell takes effect **immediately after the circumstance is met** for the first time, whether or not you want it to, and then *contingency* ends.

As you can see, *contingency* occurs after the triggering circumstance (the same way readied actions do). As a result, if you declare the triggering circumstance as "when someone casts a *meteor swarm* in an area that includes me", the contingent *banishment* spell will only take effect after *meteor swarm* finishes being cast.

Since the duration of [*meteor swarm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meteor-swarm) is instantaneous, there's no extra step between the spell being successfully cast and the meteors being brought down (and doing damage). Thus, the spell would only trigger after you'd already been hit by the spell.

---

It doesn't matter since the timing doesn't work, but even if you found a way to cast *banishment* on yourself before the *meteor swarm* hit you, it wouldn't help; since you would be incapacitated the moment you finished casting the spell, the spell would instantly end and you'd immediately be un-banished, as [Jeremy Crawford confirms here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/791042533975400448). (...Assuming you're on your native plane, of course.)

So even if you managed to find a way to banish yourself before the *meteor swarm* went off, you'd find yourself back where you were before anything else happened.

Comment: Duration instantaneous doesn't always mean that the after effect ends immediately. For example *Animate Dead*. A DM might rule that the Meteor Swarm doesn't hit you instantaneously, especially since it allows a DEX saving  throw.

Comment: @Vylix: Sure, a DM could rule otherwise, but that's beyond the scope of what the spell says. *Animate dead* occurs instantaneously. The creatures it summons are not kept animated by the spell; they stay animated, because the spell says so. *Meteor swarm* says meteors strike the specified areas when you cast the spell, not some time later. By the rules, there's no extra step between getting done casting the spell and the spell taking effect.

Comment: You might also want to note that _banishment_ only incapacitates the target if they are native to the plane you're on. Banishing yourself (as a human) while on the Plane of Fire would not incapacitate you. You'd still have to pick a better trigger to avoid the _meteor swarm_, though.